# PayPal POST payment not working on mobile browsers

Tags: vb.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a web application written in VB.net. I implemented the payment via paypal.
When I make a payment via pc there is no problem, but when I make a payment via mobile I have some problems.
I can't read the paypal parameters on my return page.
I used httpwebrequest for read the info from paypal, but the variables request.form is empty, so the response is "INVALID".

is there anyone who can help me??? please...

Comment: We're going to need to have a look at your code to be able to figure out what's going on...

Comment: Hi, have you seen my code?
Do you know where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
        Dim objHttp As HttpWebRequest

        objHttp = WebRequest.Create("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr")
            objHttp.Method = "POST"

        objHttp.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        Dim param As Byte() = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength)
        Dim strRequest As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param)
        Dim ipnPost As String = strRequest

        strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate"
        objHttp.ContentLength = strRequest.Length

        'Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        Dim streamOut As New StreamWriter(objHttp.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
        streamOut.Write(strRequest)
        streamOut.Close()

        Dim streamIn As New StreamReader(objHttp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        Dim strResponse As String = streamIn.ReadToEnd()
        streamIn.Close()

        Dim myHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(objHttp.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        Dim strIdTransazione = Request.Form("txn_id")
        Dim strDscTransazione = Request.Form("payment_status")

        'HttpStatusCode.myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode()

        If myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then

        Else

        end if
```